# What is the at sign in the htmlAttribues of the HtmlHelpers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In the following HtmlHelper:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Username, new { id = "username", @class = "textbox"})
```

Some attributes like `class` have an @ before it while others don't. what does at sign mean there?

Comment: You only need the `@` for reserved keywords

Comment: well the reason I didn't find anything in my search is that I thought its only specific for the htmlhelpers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class` is a reserved word in c#, so it cannot be used as a variable name, for making it valid variable name we need to add `@` sign in start of it, it can be used for making a reserved word a valid variable whenever needed.

Answer (score 2):

> Some attributes like class have an @ before it while others don't

that is because the C# language has a keyword `class` already. Only to negate its meaning you use `@` . The same thing goes for the C# keyword `type` and html input element attribute `type`